# How to disable SSH in GitBash and use HTTPS instead

Tags: git, https, ssh

I'm using SSH at the moment when connecting to Bitbucket and suddenly the port 22 where Bitbucket uses has been blocked so I decided to use HTTPS option instead. How to disable the ssh in git bash and use HTTPS instead? I already reinstalled git but it still it uses SSH/Putty to connect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not at git settings, but in your repository settings.

You need to change the address of your remote repository and specify the `https://` protocol

```
git remote set-url origin <repo-https-url>
```

However with https you'll have to type your password on each push/pull operation, but see [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/11343).

Comment: works like charm thanks! my mindset is to get rid of ssh where I should only just have to change the remote url lol.

Comment: now my next problem is getting rid of the annoying password prompt :)

Comment: I have a submodule with a URL starting with `https://github.com/` but when I run `git submodule update --init` it tries to use SSH, it says `Host key verification failed.` and `fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:`. What else do I have to change to make it use HTTPS?